How to fix Roblox Deformation when rotate
I'm having trouble with importing a Roblox avatar to Blender. Specifically, I'm having difficulty with posing it after import. I've watched several tutorials on how to import and rig an R16 Roblox avatar, but I always encounter issues. After adding bones, whenever I rotate a specific part, it widens and deforms. This happens every time, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone share a tutorial video on how to correctly import and rig a Roblox avatar without encountering deformation issues? Alternatively, can someone help me troubleshoot this problem? Thank you!

If the character is supposed to have rigid limbs, don't parent it With Automatic Weights but With Empty Groups, then assign the parts you want to the vertex groups you want. If this doesn't fix your problem please tell more, show screenshots, maybe share your file

If the character is supposed to have rigid limbs, don't parent it With Automatic Weights but With Empty Groups, then assign the parts you want to the vertex groups that have the name of the bone that is supposed to control them:


How do I do that? I'm sort of new to the blender and it's controls and features so I'm not sure how to do anything.

I've added a screenshot, I hope it helps

Okay, I'm looking at the screenshot and it appears I'm in the right place. However, I don't think I named it with vertex group since I'm looking at yours and It doesn't appear exactly as mine. Here's some information: It is an imported Roblox figure (R16 so it has more parts) that I'm trying to pair with a rig from Rigify. I'm not sure where I went wrong. I might need to learn how to redo the entire thing since I have a feeling I did something wrong when I was importing.

Here's a link to the roblox avater: [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ya4quXcdtPpMePJJojmgAtpDZsk_udOu?usp=sharing]
